# Data Mapper - Creating Fluent mapper config in route

Tags: spring, apache-camel, datamapper

Is there any good data mapper like transport available for Camel, something along the lines of Smooks(I've used this in the past and it was really good) or any etl like feature.  I tried to make use of Dozer but that doesn't work in the way we want, also too much of code and mapping strategies.
I am trying to create a mapper for a legacy EDI interface. Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JBoss Fuse Eclipse Tooling for Camel has a visual data mapper where you can configure the mapping without coding.

- http://tools.jboss.org/features/apachecamel.html
- http://www.davsclaus.com/2015/04/apache-camel-eclipse-tooling-for-visual.html

Comment: Thanks @Claus Ibsen  managed to install the eclipse tooling and exploring the features.